# ImportError: cannot import name 'authenticate'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, authentication, django-rest-framework

When I code `from rest_framework.compat import authenticate`

the pycharm remains me there is an error:

```
  File "/Users/yindeyong/PycharmProjects/newsapi/article/serilaizes.py", line 16, in <module>
    from rest_framework.compat import authenticate
ImportError: cannot import name 'authenticate'
```

Django 2.0.4

djangorestframework    3.9.4

Any friend know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you tell us where is the documentation about `authenticate` at `rest_framework.compat`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `restframework.compat` package which you're importing from is just for backward compatibility!

Is there any reason you're importing from that??!

If you're new to `Django Rest Framework` (`DRF`), just remark that you're using almost latest version of `rest_framework` and you're up to date, and you don't need any refrence to backward compatibility! It will help you to face more less to problems!

Anyway, `authentication` package of `DRF` (Django Rest Framework) is directly available from `rest_framework`! You could use it simply as something like this:

```
from rest_framework import authentication
```

Comment: Hi friends can you help with another question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56487261/fixed-default-value-provided-issue-with-django

Comment: The link is not Available! Check that your provided link is correct?

Answer (score 2):

From looking at the Django rest framework guide it seems that the only authentication supported is imported through:

```
from rest_framework import authentication
```

There is no authenticate within compat.py that I could find.

Comment: Hi friends can you help with another question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56487261/fixed-default-value-provided-issue-with-django