# Fixed default value provided issue with Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

This is my model:

```
created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

after I run it.I receives the following error:

article.Article.publish_date: (fields.W161) Fixed default value provided.
        HINT: It seems you set a fixed date / time / datetime value as default for this field. This may not be what you want. If you want to have the current date as default, use `django.utils.timezone.now`

While I replace the code like this:

```
created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)
```

it still remains me :NameError: name 'django' is not defined

Any friend can help with this?

Comment: `created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now())
`?

Comment: NameError: name 'django' is not defined

Comment: `from django.utils import timezone; created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())`

Comment: still not work,I also tried from django.utils import timezone; created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)  Thank you for help.

Comment: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29028

Answer (score 2):

This is default for now. It will add the time object got created.

```
created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
from django.utils import timezone
today = timezone.now

class Myclass(models.Model):
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=today)
```